# ASP Login Control - Checking login status

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, login-control, loginstatus

I want to use my code behind (C#) to check and see if a user is logged in or not on page load. I assume this is really basic, but I'm still new to .net

This is basically what I want:

```
if(loggedIn == true){ do something }
```

Comment: On a side note, when checking if something is true or false and the property is a boolean value, you can just use `if (booleanProperty)` or `if (!booleanProperty)`. First one is `if(true)` second is `if(false)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using the built in .net Forms Authentication, then you can use the following

```
if ( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
     do something
}
```

Make sure you have your settings in the web.config set up for using FormsAuthentication

Answer (score 4):

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // do something
}
```

assuming you're using FormsAuthentication.

If however, you're using a Session based login, you can do a nullable check, just like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["somevalue"] != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether User.Identity.Name is an empty string or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Membership` you can just call `GetUser()` with no arguments. It results the logged in user if the user is logged in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339.aspx

```
Membership.GetUser()
```